# Kotlin kapt, gradle and ebean plugin build failure

Tags: gradle, kotlin, ebean, kapt

build.gradle file looks like:

```
group 'styleru-ikomarov'
version '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
    ext.html_version = "0.6.2"
    ext.ktor_version = "0.3.3"
    ext.squash_version = "0.2.2"
    ext.gson_version = "2.8.1"
    ext.ehcache_version = "3.0.0.m4"
    ext.jodatime_version = "2.3"
    ext.slf4j_version = "1.7.5"
    ext.ebean_version = "10.3.1"
    ext.ebean_plugin_version = "10.2.2"
    ext.ebean_querybean_generator = "10.1.2"
    ext.mysql_version = "5.1.6"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.ebean:ebean-gradle-plugin:$ebean_plugin_version"
        classpath "mysql:mysql-connector-java:$mysql_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'ebean'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx.html" }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx" }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor" }
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/squash" }
    maven { url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time" }
    maven { url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.ktor/ktor-jetty" }
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += [file("$buildDir/generated/source/kapt/main")]
}

dependencies {
    kapt "io.ebean:kotlin-querybean-generator:$ebean_querybean_generator"

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"

    compile "org.jetbrains.ktor:ktor-core:$ktor_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.ktor:ktor-jetty:$ktor_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.ktor:ktor-locations:$ktor_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktor_version"

    compile "org.ehcache:ehcache:$ehcache_version"

    compile "io.ebean:ebean:$ebean_version"
    compile "io.ebean:ebean-querybean:$ebean_version"

    //TODO("should i remove this dependency?")
    compile"mysql:mysql-connector-java:$mysql_version"

    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gson_version"

    compile "joda-time:joda-time:$jodatime_version"

    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:$slf4j_version"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4j_version"
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

ebean {
    debugLevel = 9
    //packages = ['dbo.categories']
    queryBeans = true
    kotlin = true
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}

test {
    useTestNG()
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    testLogging.exceptionFormat = 'full'
}
```

The stacktrace while trying to perform ./gradlew clean --stacktrace:

> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'diabetics'.
>         at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
>         at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
>         at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:529)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:90)
>         at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
>         at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
>         at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:241)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:214)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:207)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
>     Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot change
>     dependencies of configuration ':kapt' after it has been resolved.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.validateMutation(DefaultConfiguration.java:600)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$2.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:149)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.assertMutable(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:267)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:158)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.add(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:81)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.doAdd(DefaultDependencyHandler.java:84)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.add(DefaultDependencyHandler.java:61)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.add(DefaultDependencyHandler.java:57)
>         at org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler$add.call(Unknown
>     Source)
>         at org.avaje.ebean.gradle.EnhancePlugin.hookQueryBeans(EnhancePlugin.groovy:63)
>         at org.avaje.ebean.gradle.EnhancePlugin$_apply_closure1.doCall(EnhancePlugin.groovy:35)
>         at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
>         at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
>         at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
>         at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
>         at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
>         at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
>         at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
>         ... 44 more

As I'm quite new to both kotlin and IntelliJ IDEA, it would be very hard for me to solve this issue on my own.

Notice, that my DBO classes are getting enhanced with the help of IDEA plugin for ebean, but as it comes to generating finders and query-beans, I am struck as none of samples provided for ebean+gradle+kotlin works for me.

Comment: what is your gradle version, Intellij version?

Comment: Thanks for attention, finally, the problem was solved by removing the coroutines "enable" line. I don't know why it worked out, but writing it back makes the critical exception being thrown during compile-time again...

Comment: Note that there is an example at: https://github.com/ebean-orm-examples/example-gradle-kotlin   ... also note I often don't get time to watch stackoverflow (so the Ebean google group is a good alternative to ask questions)

Comment: Yep, thx. I was trying (and finally succeeded) looking through this example, as there are no others :) The question is closed btw, solution found.